# Sculpting Brushes Not Working as Intended

Tags: sculpting, sculpt, sculpt-mode, brushes

I'm trying to learn Blender in order to sculpt characters, but the brushes are not working as intended. I've tried following sculpting tutorials, but they're useless because all of the brushes are having the same effect no matter the settings. Every time, it just makes one large, smooth bump on the clay sphere, then refuses to make any additional effects. The Clay brush actually does the opposite; it removes one large smooth section of the sphere. The Grab brush is completely non-functional.
I've altered the radius of the brush, the strength— no effect. I've reset the scale— no effect. I saw a post about something that sounded similar— about brushes not working effectively; they added a post saying that they figured it out by adding modifiers, but I don't know what that means in terms of sculpting.
I would appreciate any insight from anyone with more experience! I'm currently getting nowhere.

*edit: I just needed to apply the Command 3 modifier! Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Further info you should give:

- Blender version you are using
- Tutorial you are following.

I'm guessing you are following a bad tutorial or something. Or perhaps the surface you are trying to sculpt has too less geometry.

Here is one of the nice tutorials that might be helpful: https://youtu.be/ijdhJsN2Iiw