# while sculpting in blender, my inflate brush shows pink lines but doesn't inflate the geometry

Tags: sculpting, brushes

I'm Vishakh. I'm new to sculpting in Blender. While sculpting in blender, my inflate brush shows pink lines but doesn't inflate the geometry. I'm not sure what settings need to modified so I reset to factory but still same is there after reset. This is not an artifact. This happened with my Grab brush as well. Once in a while it actually sculpts along with showing these lines. I'm sure I've done something silly, but can't identify what.
[image: snapshot of the line I'm talking about.]

please help me.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/295884/sculpting-brushes-not-working-as-intended?rq=1